# Local Win+Ubuntu: ssh from Win to Ubuntu via the Internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, router, ssh

I have two computers, Win10 & Ubuntu 18.04, behind a router, connected to the Internet. On both, Internet works OK. I want to give access to someone to do remote work on Ubuntu (not Win). The remote work will be done via x11vnc and a VNC viewer. On Ubuntu, I have OpenSSH and x11vnc set-up and ready.

Before I test VNC, I first want to test basic ssh: by ssh-ing from Win through the Internet to Ubuntu, as if I were coming from outside. No pem keys yet, just password. I've tried to ssh from Win Powershell to Ubuntu using my outside IP (how my router is seen from outside), but all I see is a blinking cursor, no login prompt. What's needed for ssh from Win to Ubuntu to work?

Ubuntu:

1. OpenSSH running,
2. ssh port allowed in ufw
3. If Win uses port 22 for ssh, should Ubuntu use port 23 for ssh, so
   as to not conflict?

Win:

1. sh client on Win (Powershell)
2. Known outside IP (whatsmyip)

Router: should some ports be forwarded? If so, which ones?

The router software wants this info:

1. select device IP (Outside IP? Local IP? If local, the router, Win or
   Ubuntu)?
2. starting port
3. ending port
4. "remote IP and port" (I assume this is where I allow only select IPs
   to connect from outside so it would be my external IP)

EDIT: ------ more info ------

[image: Port forwarding config on the router]

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ';22' on Ubuntu:
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1158/sshd
tcp6  0   0 :::22        :::*        LISTEN   1158/sshd    

cat /etc/ssh/sshd.config on Ubuntu:
cat: /etc/ssh/sshd.config: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is leaving the SSH and VNC servers on the systems on default settings, and separate them with the port forwarding. Having multiple systems using the same port in the same network does not cause conflicts, as the systems are only listening on the port, and clients connect using the IP address.

From within the network you use the internal IPs, let's assume `192.168.0.10` for Ubuntu. To SSH from Windows to Ubuntu you `ssh user@192.168.0.10`. Get the internal connectivity working correctly before thinking about external access.

For connecting from outside you need to configure port forwarding on the router, for example 10010. By what you describe I'd configure port forwarding thus:

```
Device IP: 192.168.0.10
Starting port: 22
Ending port: 22
Remote IP: blank
Remote port: 10010
```

Then you should be able to SSH from outside to Ubuntu `ssh user@<PublicIP> -p 10010`.

The default port for VNC is 5900+N, N being the display number - usually it's 0 so port 5900 is enough. You can allow access to the Ubuntu with VNC by creating a similar port forwarding rules. For example you could use 10590 as the remote port and 5900 for Starting and Ending port. The VNC client will then connect to the internal system using the public IP and remote port.

To test the access from outside you need to actually access from outside. One way is connecting a system to the internet using a phone hotspot instead of the router; it won't be in the same internal network anymore.

Note that for port forwarding to be reliable you should configure your Ubuntu system with a static IP address.

*This is just general advice based no the available info. Exact implementation advice can't be given without exact details.*

Comment: Thanks. Local ssh Win->Ubuntu works. If I can't test an "outside-style" connection from inside, I'll try from a nearby FedOffice, then report back. Why do we forward the port from 10010 to 22? Is it because 22 is a common port for ssh (a target for hackers) so we use an uncommon port (10010) so as to not use 22? Does the router block outside ssh connections to port 22 (on Ubuntu), unless we forward the port? Thanks again.

Comment: Right at the first go :-) Nothing prevents you from using the standard ports 22 and 5900 for remote ports as well, but they are often obfuscated with random ports precisely for that reason. Port forwarding is a must whichever remote port you choose. The router's firewall will by default drop all incoming new connection requests. Port forwarding configures the firewall to accept incoming connections to `PublicIP:AllowedPort`, and the router to forward the traffic with that IP/port combination to the specified internal IP address.

Comment: Thanks. My FedExOffice idea failed: they don't allow Powershell, not even "normal" cmd. I don't want to lug my laptop to some wi-fi hotspot. So what I'll try next: rent a cheap Amazon EC2 Linux instance, and try to ssh from it into my Ubuntu, since that instance is "outside". If ssh works this way, I'll assume VNC will work, too (other than different ports)..

Comment: .... and why didn't I think about that... :-D It reminded me of something else - online SSH clients. See for example [https://sshwifty.herokuapp.com/](https://sshwifty.herokuapp.com/). I'd definitely use an obfuscated port with an online SSH, and change it immediately if the test is successful. If you don't have an EC2 yet, it's free for first 12 months.

Comment: Thanks. I tried sshwifty. I temporarily forwarded 22 for Ubuntu (just for a few minutes), since sshwifty doesn't allow me to set the port.. It looked like sshwifty saw the Ubuntu from outside (it asked me if I recognize this server), but the password connection itself failed, not sure exactly why "ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password], no supported methods remain". I'll reboot Ubuntu (just in case), then try via EC2 on an obfuscated port (I removed the 22 forwarding from the router, of course)

Comment: Tried from Amazon. Again, it looks like Ubuntu is seen ("do you recognize this server") but I can't log in with a password "Permission denied, please try again". In the router config, in the "Enter the remote port and IP" section, there are "Destination port", "Starting port" and "Remote IP". I get "Remote IP": the IP of the Amazon's instance), but "destination" and "starting" port are confusing: I entered "10010".in both. This is separate from the LAN section, with "Starting Port:" and "Ending Port" (both 22)

Comment: `Remote IP` limits the access to your server to that IP address. You reach _something_ but what...please add to your question a screenshot of your port forwarding page (mask the public IP!), the actual internal IP of the Ubuntu machine (no need to mask 192.168-address) and the output of commands `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':22'` and `cat /etc/ssh/sshd.config`. Also please add description of how exactly you tested from the EC2, what commands exactly you gave (mask the public IP) and what results you got. Best if you can repeat the process and copy everything directly from the EC2 shell.

Comment: That'll put all the relevant info in one place so other community members can pitch in without digging details up from a long comment thread.

Comment: I posted the info (for the benefit of others), but I solved the problem. When I was done testing yesterday, I shut down the Open SSH service... duh (it's not on auto-start). Upon re-launching, I'm able to log in from Amazon. Thanks.

Comment: LOL! Happens... this is how anecdotes are made :-D I'm sure you'll get it done from here. Of course if you have probs you can't find solutions for, you know where to find SU... Good luck!